# Why does mysql-connector for .NET only provide 32-bits version?

Tags: .net, 32bit-64bit, mysql-connector

MySQL connector for .NET dowload:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

However, it has only 32 bits version.
But my server is 64 bits windows, and need a 64 bits connector.

If using the 32-bit connector, my web program will also work at 32-bit mode. This is a .NET feature. My 16 GB server memory，only 4GB can be used.

So, the 64-bit connector is required.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: How does "server is 64 bits windows" imply "need a 64 bits connector"? `How should I solve this problem?` - use the 32-bit connector?

Comment: The application using the driver can be 32-bit and can use the driver even on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: If using the 32-bit connector, my web program will also work at 32-bit mode.  This is a .NET feature.  My 16 GB server memory，only 4G can be used.

Comment: Click the info bubble to read: *Note: MySQL Installer is 32 bit, but will install both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries*

Comment: @HansPassant I can't find that note on the connector download page. The info bubble only says it's fully managed.

Comment: @HansPassant  Yes, I saw the bubble, but it is not conspicuous.  You are correct, and help me solve this problem.  Thank you very much!